# Findall to div tag using beautiful soup yields blank return

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, findall

```
<div class="columns small-5 medium-4 cell header">Ref No.</div>
<div class="columns small-7 medium-8 cell">110B60329</div>
```

Website is https://www.saa.gov.uk/search/?SEARCHED=1&ST=&SEARCH_TERM=city+of+edinburgh%2C+BOSWALL+PARKWAY%2C+EDINBURGH&ASSESSOR_ID=&SEARCH_TABLE=valuation_roll_cpsplit&DISPLAY_COUNT=10&TYPE_FLAG=CP&ORDER_BY=PROPERTY_ADDRESS&H_ORDER_BY=SET+DESC&DRILL_SEARCH_TERM=BOSWALL+PARKWAY%2C+EDINBURGH&DD_TOWN=EDINBURGH&DD_STREET=BOSWALL+PARKWAY&UARN=110B60329&PPRN=000000000001745&ASSESSOR_IDX=10&DISPLAY_MODE=FULL#results

I would like to run a loop and return '110B60329'. I have ran beautiful soup and done a find_all(div), I then define the 2 different tags as head and data based on their class. I then ran iteration through the 'head' tags hoping it would return the info in the div tag i have defined as data .

Python returns a blank (cmd prompt reprinted the filepth).

Would anyone kindly know how i might fix this. My full code is.....thanks

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import csv


url = 'https://www.saa.gov.uk/search/?SEARCHED=1&ST=&SEARCH_TERM=city+of+edinburgh%2C+BOSWALL+PARKWAY%2C+EDINBURGH&ASSESSOR_ID=&SEARCH_TABLE=valuation_roll_cpsplit&DISPLAY_COUNT=10&TYPE_FLAG=CP&ORDER_BY=PROPERTY_ADDRESS&H_ORDER_BY=SET+DESC&DRILL_SEARCH_TERM=BOSWALL+PARKWAY%2C+EDINBURGH&DD_TOWN=EDINBURGH&DD_STREET=BOSWALL+PARKWAY&UARN=110B60329&PPRN=000000000001745&ASSESSOR_IDX=10&DISPLAY_MODE=FULL#results'

baseurl = 'https://www.saa.gov.uk'

session = requests.session()

response = session.get(url)

# content of search page in soup 
html= soup(response.content,"lxml")   
properties_col = html.find_all('div')



for col in properties_col:
    ref = 'n/a'
    des = 'n/a'

    head = col.find_all("div",{"class": "columns small-5 medium-4 cell header"}) 

    data = col.find_all("div",{"class":"columns small-7 medium-8 cell"})

    for i,elem in enumerate(head):
    #for i in range(elems):
        if head [i].text == "Ref No.":
            ref = data[i].text
            print ref
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by two ways.

1) If you are sure that the website that your are scraping won't change its content you can find all divs by that class and get the content by providing an index.

2) Find all left side divs (The titles) and if one of them matches what you want get the next sibling to get the text.

Example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

url = 'https://www.saa.gov.uk/search/?SEARCHED=1&ST=&SEARCH_TERM=city+of+edinburgh%2C+BOSWALL+PARKWAY%2C+EDINBURGH&ASSESSOR_ID=&SEARCH_TABLE=valuation_roll_cpsplit&DISPLAY_COUNT=10&TYPE_FLAG=CP&ORDER_BY=PROPERTY_ADDRESS&H_ORDER_BY=SET+DESC&DRILL_SEARCH_TERM=BOSWALL+PARKWAY%2C+EDINBURGH&DD_TOWN=EDINBURGH&DD_STREET=BOSWALL+PARKWAY&UARN=110B60329&PPRN=000000000001745&ASSESSOR_IDX=10&DISPLAY_MODE=FULL#results'

baseurl = 'https://www.saa.gov.uk'

session = requests.session()

response = session.get(url)

# content of search page in soup 
html = soup(response.content,"lxml")

#Method 1
LeftBlockData = html.find_all("div", class_="columns small-7 medium-8 cell")
Reference = LeftBlockData[0].get_text().strip()
Description = LeftBlockData[2].get_text().strip()
print(Reference)
print(Description)

#Method 2
for column in html.find_all("div", class_="columns small-5 medium-4 cell header"):
    RightColumn = column.next_sibling.next_sibling.get_text().strip()
    if "Ref No." in column.get_text().strip():
        print (RightColumn)
    if "Description" in column.get_text().strip():
        print (RightColumn)
```

The prints will output (in order):

> 110B60329
>
> STORE
>
> 110B60329
>
> STORE

Your problem is that you are trying to match a node text that have a lot of tabs with a non-spaced string.

For example your `head [i].text`variable contains 
                                    `Ref No.`, so if you compare it with `Ref No.` it'll give a false result. Striping it will solve.

Comment: Hi there, I followed the same logic to try and lift the 'Rateable Value from the same page by adding lines                                                                                               RightBlockData = html.find_all("div", class_="columns small-12 medium-5")
Rateable_Value = RightBlockData[2].get_text().strip()

Comment: However I got error RightBlockData = html.find_all("div", class_="columns small-12 medium-5")
Rateable_Value = RightBlockData[2].get_text().strip()

Comment: Any idea why Zroq?

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.saa.gov.uk/search/?SEARCHED=1&ST=&SEARCH_TERM=city+of+edinburgh%2C+BOSWALL+PARKWAY%2C+EDINBURGH&ASSESSOR_ID=&SEARCH_TABLE=valuation_roll_cpsplit&DISPLAY_COUNT=10&TYPE_FLAG=CP&ORDER_BY=PROPERTY_ADDRESS&H_ORDER_BY=SET+DESC&DRILL_SEARCH_TERM=BOSWALL+PARKWAY%2C+EDINBURGH&DD_TOWN=EDINBURGH&DD_STREET=BOSWALL+PARKWAY&UARN=110B60329&PPRN=000000000001745&ASSESSOR_IDX=10&DISPLAY_MODE=FULL#results")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
for row in soup.find_all(class_='table-row'):

    print(row.get_text(strip=True, separator='|').split('|'))
```

out:

```
['Ref No.', '110B60329']
['Office', 'LOTHIAN VJB']
['Description', 'STORE']
['Property Address', '29 BOSWALL PARKWAY', 'EDINBURGH', 'EH5 2BR']
['Proprietor', 'SCOTTISH MIDLAND CO-OP SOCIETY LTD.']
['Tenant', 'PROPRIETOR']
['Occupier']
['Net Annual Value', '£1,750']
['Marker']
['Rateable Value', '£1,750']
['Effective Date', '01-APR-10']
['Other Appeal', 'NO']
['Reval Appeal', 'NO']
```

`get_text()` is very powerful tool, you can strip the white space and put separator in the text.

You can use this method to get clean data and filter it.